# Adding a UIButton to UITableView but can't scroll down to the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableView and I want to add a button just underneath the table. The table is bigger than the screen so to get to the button, I need to scroll down to it. The problem is, the screen will scroll to just above where the button is. So I can drag the screen slightly and the button is visible but when I let go, the screen springs back and I can't get to the button.

The button is set up as follows

```
for(int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; i++)
    {
        UIButton *but = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        float xPosition = but.frame.origin.x;
        float xGap = (self.view.frame.size.width - (but.frame.size.width)*2)/3;
        if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i < [buttonArray count] - 1))
        {
            xPosition = xGap;
        }
        else if ((i % 2 == 1) && (i < [buttonArray count] - 1))
        {
            xPosition = (xGap * 2) + but.frame.size.width;
        }
        else
        {
            xPosition = (self.view.frame.size.width - but.frame.size.width)/2;
        }
        //Add space between row of buttons
        if(i > 0)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                yPosition+=but.frame.size.height;
                CGRect screenRect = [[tableView superview] bounds];

                //Add extra space between row of buttons
                float fGap = (screenRect.size.height / 100.0) * 4.5;
                yPosition+=fGap;
            }
        }
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, but.frame.size.width, but.frame.size.height);
        but.frame = rect;
        [but addTarget:self action:@selector(genericMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        CGRect screenRect = [self.view bounds];
        CGFloat fHeight = screenRect.size.height;

        float fMargin = (fHeight / 100.0) * 0.8;

        but.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, fMargin, 0);

        [tableView addSubview:but];
    }
}
```

So I go through an array of buttons (only one button in the array in my current case) and set up the frames and position them into columns and add it as a subview to the tableView. Things I've tried are:

- Increase the table footer size. This just makes the gap between the table and button increase and I still can't scroll down as far as the button.
- Add the button to the footer. This kind of worked. I could get to the button, but the button was always on screen, not just static below the table.
- Add the button to a separate view below the table and add that view to the viewController.view. This didn't work at all and the button wasn't displayed.
- Set the tableView.tableFooterView equal to the button. This also kind of worked and I could reach the button but it wouldn't work when there is more than one button in the array above.

Comment: You should add your button to the table view's `tableFooterView` instead.

Comment: I tried doing [tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:but] but the button doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: You should probably add your own `UIView` as the actual `tableFooterView`, then add your button as a subview of it.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that already and the button wasn't displayed in the footer. The only time the button displays correctly is when I add it to the UITableView but then I can't scroll down to actually click on it.

Comment: Could you update your question with the latest code?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom view. Inside that view you should add all the buttons created using  buttonArray. Now, assign this custom view to tableFooterView.

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:properFrame];
for(int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; i++)
{
      //...calculation of frame and other stuff
      [customView addSubview:but];
}
tableView.tableFooterView = customView;
```

This should solve your scrolling issue.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it and it does allow me to scroll further but unfortunately the button doesn't appear on the screen when I do it this way. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Have you adjusted the button frame, given that you are now adding it as a subview of the tableFooterView, not the tableView?

Comment: Yes, as a test I set the frame to have x=0 and y=0 but keep it's original size. This should put it in the top left corner of the tableFooterView, right?

Comment: OK. For some reason, it doesn't add it to the top left corner when I do that.

Comment: where does it attach? update the question with new code and screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to make bottom view as stable,Take a UIView at the bottom
  of UITableView.
- If you will use TableFooterView,It will be at the end of cell .
  [image: View]

[image: XIB]

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to have the UIButton always be underneath the UITableView. I'm able to add the view so that it is static and always on the screen but I'm not able to add it in so that the button is always below the table and you have to scroll past the table to view it. I've added a custom view to the bottom of the UITableView but unfortunately the button doesn't appear on screen when I do that.